# Input Service for Jetpack Compose

Tags: input, android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard

I'm building my own soft keyboard for my app.
I was wondering if there was a way of popping open my custom keyboard instead of the default android soft Keyboard.
For example, when clicking on a TextField, I would like my custom keyboard to be the input source.